# Is there a way to define a named constant/parameter in a single-statement SQL query?

Tags: sql, vertica

Tried to do something like:

```
WITH
dates as (SELECT '2015-01-01' as start, '2016-01-01' as end)
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE start_date >= dates.start AND end_date <= dates.end
```

But got the error message "Relation 'dates' does not exist" (in Vertica). Is there any proper way to define a constant/parameter. In real example the query contains multiple selects over a defined time range, hence I'd like to maintain the values constants/parameters in a single place to allow them to be reused in the nested subqueries.

IF possible, I'd like to refrain from DECLARE/SET-like statements, where a separate line is required.

Comment: Why is this tagged both Vertica and MySQL?  These are very different databases.  I removed the MySQL tag because your question suggests that `WITH` works, and it is not supported by MySQL.

Comment: I was not aware that MySQL doesn't support `WITH` and I've added MySQL because of StackOverflow suggestion. Thanks for the corrections, @GordonLinoff

Comment: Which client are you using to connect?  Are these vsql scripts?

Comment: @woot currently it's DBeaver (on Windows), by vsql will be installed soon as I'll get a macbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `dates` in the `FROM` clause if you want it in the query.  You can do this as:

```
WITH dates as (SELECT '2015-01-01' as start, '2016-01-01' as end)
SELECT t.*
FROM my_table t JOIN
     dates d
     ON t.start_date >= d.start AND t.end_date <= d.end;
```

Note:  You can also do this with a `CROSS JOIN`.  I often write queries as:

```
WITH params as (
     SELECT '2015-01-01' as start, '2016-01-01' as end
    )
SELECT t.*
FROM params CROSS JOIN
     my_table t
WHERE t.start_date >= params.start AND t.end_date <= params.end;
```

Comment: So using a constant comes at a `JOIN` price, right? Which will make the code even less readable, given that there are lots of selects in subqueries :(

Answer (score 3):

I would still do what @GordonLinoff mentioned (I doubt it has much impact on the query plan), but in case you really don't want to or like the feature I will show at the end...

You mentioned you were going to use vsql.  You can do variables there.

```
\set start '2015-01-01'
\set end '2016-01-01'
SELECT * 
FROM  my_table 
WHERE start_date >= :start 
AND   end_date <= :end;
```

Which is I guess kind of nice because you can also do things like:

```
\set start ''`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`''
```

Or echo the result of any command into a variable that you can use as a variable in your sql statement. Note that this variable is quite literal and you need to include any punctuation, quoting, etc.  It isn't just a value, it's more like a template.